# ROS rosconsole.config logging configuration file in common XML?

Tags: logging, log4j, ros, log4cxx

Is it possible to also use commonly known XML-format for the ROS logging configuration file?

Such as:

```
<Configuration>
  <filter  ... />
  <Appenders>
    <appender ... >
      <filter  ... />
    </appender>
    ...
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="name1">
      <filter  ... />
    </Logger>
    ...
    <Root level="level">
      <AppenderRef ref="name"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

instead of the standard properties-format, which looks like this for instance:

```
appender.stdout.type = Console
# ... other appender properties
appender.file.type = File
# ... other appender properties
logger.app = INFO, stdout, file
logger.app.name = com.example.app
 
# is equivalent to:
# appender.stdout.type = Console
# appender.stdout.name = stdout
# ...
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = file
# ...
logger.app.name = com.example.app
logger.app.level = INFO
logger.app.appenderRef.$1.ref = stdout
logger.app.appenderRef.$2.ref = file
```

(c.f. [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already recognized, that log4cxx is used by ROS under the hood which may also supports the XML-format you've mentioned.

log4cxx differences between the [PropertyConfigurator](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1_property_configurator.html) for the known ROS format and the [DOMConfigurator](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1xml_1_1_d_o_m_configurator.html) for the XML format mentioned by you.

Unfortunately, ROS does not forseen a way to use the DOMConfigurator, since a look inside the [implementation](https://github.com/ros/rosconsole/blob/noetic-devel/src/rosconsole/impl/rosconsole_log4cxx.cpp#L153) (`log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configure(config_file);`) shows, that the PropertyConfigurator is used hard coded here.

**This means: Without changing it manually and recompiling ROS, there is no way around the PropertyConfigurator.**

Comment: That's not what I wanted to hear, but it helps. Thank you!